# JQuery - Nested AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to perform a nested AJAX call using the following code. The nested call doesn't seem to work. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "/public/customcontroller/dosomething",
cache: false,
dataType: "html",
success: function(html_input)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/public/customcontroller/getjobstatus",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html_input){
        alert(html_input);
        }
    });                                                                       
}
});
```

Comment: Depends, is the first call successful? Otherwise the function in `success` is never called.

Comment: I would call `html_input` something different in the inner function

Comment: The first call is successful. I renamed html_input to html_response in the inner function.. Still no luck..

Comment: Just curious, why don't you have `/public/customcontroller/dosomething` return the data you're after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be having thread-type issues, given that the outside call is asynchronous and may go out of scope before the success handler can come into play.  Try breaking the success call out into a separate function.

Comment: Would love to see an example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "/public/customcontroller/dosomething",
cache: false,
dataType: "html",
async: false,
success: function(html_input)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/public/customcontroller/getjobstatus",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html_input){
        alert(html_input);
        }
    });                                                                       
}
});
```

Comment: :In the above code instead of "dataType" you should use "datatype".

Comment: @suraj http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings states that the option is named dataType.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `async/await` syntax.

```
async function foo () {
    var html_input = await $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/public/customcontroller/dosomething",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html"
    })

    var html_input2 = await $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/public/customcontroller/getjobstatus",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html"
    })

    alert(html_input2)
}
foo().catch(e => console.log('some error:', e))
```