# Nested Ajax problem. How to debug/solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a lot of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548241/jquery-nested-ajax) about nested Ajax problems, but I can't figure out whats wrong with my own.

The problem I see is that the server side script doesn't receive the form values in the nested Ajax call.

On the client side I get that `result2` is null.

The nested Ajax code is encapsulated with `// problem`.

Can anyone see why the nested Ajax doesn't receive the form values?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').live('submit', function(){

    // ...

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/cgi-bin/ajax_confirm.pl",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //      async: false,

        data: $(this).serialize(),

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        $('div#create_result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText +
                        ", textStatus: " + textStatus +
                        ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        alert("Error occured in ajax.js confirm code.");

        },

        success: function(result){
        if (result.error) {
            $('div#create_result').text("result.error: " + result.error);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        } else { // server side script says everything is okay

            var users  = $.parseJSON(result.users);
            var owners = $.parseJSON(result.owners);

            $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            open: function() {
                $(this).children('div.dialog-text').replaceWith("<h3><b>Users</b></h3>" + makeDialogTable(users) + "<h3><b>Owners</b></h3>" + makeDialogTable(owners));
            },

            buttons: {
                Okay: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
// problem
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",

                        // generate and send parameters to server-side script
                    data: $(this).serialize(),

                    // script call was *not* successful
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        $('div#create_result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
                    },

                    success: function(result2){
                        if (result2.error) { // script returned error
                        $('div#create_result').text("result2.error: " + result2.error);
                        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
                        } else { // perl script says everything is okay
                        $('div#create_result').text("result2.success: " + result.success + ", result2.id: " + result.id);
                        $('div#create_result').addClass("success");
                        } //else
                    } // success
                    }); // ajax

                } else { // if (is_okay) { ...
                    $('div#create_result').text("Fill out the form to create an activity");
                    $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
                } // else
                }, // Okay

// problem
                Cancel: function() {
                is_okay = 0;
                $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            } // buttons
            }); // dialog
        } //else
        } // success
    }); // ajax

    // ...
```

**Update**
Here is the HTML, when shown looks like [this](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/2647/93719315.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ajaxv2.js"></script>

    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="page-body">

      <div class="create-new">
    <div id="create_result" style="display:none;">
    </div>
    <form id="create_form" name="create_form" action="" method="post">
      <input name="anchor" id="anchor" value="create" type="hidden">

      <label class="new" for="title">Title:</label>
      <input class="new" type="text" name="title" id="title" />

      <label class="new" for="owner">Owner:</label>
      <input class="new" type="text" name="owner" id="owner" /><br class="new"/>

      <label class="new" for="users">Users:</label>
      <input class="new" type="text" name="users" id="users"/>

      <label class="new" for="groups">Groups:</label>
      <input class="new" type="text" name="groups" id="groups" /><br class="new"/>

      <label class="new" for="begin_date">Begin Date:</label>
      <input class="new" type="text" id="from" name="from"/>

      <label class="new" for="end_date">End Date:</label>
      <input class="new" type="text" id="to" name="to"/><br class="new"/>

      <label class="new" for="type">Type:</label>
      <input name="ctype" id="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" /> Individuel <br/>
      <input name="ctype" id="ctypee" value="course"    type="radio" /> Course <br/>

          <button class="n" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
      </div>


      <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Can you confirm?" style="display: none;">
    <div class="dialog-text">
      <p>dialog text goes here</p>
    </div>
      </div>

      <TMPL_INCLUDE NAME="menu.tmpl">

    <table class="alerts" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>

        <tr class="header">
          <th class="activity-header">ID</th>
          <th class="activity-header">Title</th>
          <th class="activity-header">Owner</th>
          <th class="activity-header">Begin Date</th>
          <th class="activity-header">End Date</th>
          <th class="activity-header">Type</th>
          <th class="activity-header"></th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <TMPL_LOOP NAME=ROW>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="anchor" value="<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="hidden">
        <table class="alerts" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
        <tr>                                
          <td class="activity-data"><TMPL_VAR ID></td>
          <td class="activity-data"> <input name="title" id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_title"      value="<TMPL_VAR TI>" type="text" /> </td>
          <td class="activity-data"> <input name="owner" id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_owner"      value="<TMPL_VAR OW>" type="text" /> </td>
          <td class="activity-data"> <input name="from"  id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_begin_date" value="<TMPL_VAR BD>" type="text" class="datepick" /> </td>
          <td class="activity-data"> <input name="to"    id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_end_date"   value="<TMPL_VAR ED>" type="text" class="datepick" /> </td>
          <td class="activity-data"> <input name="ctype" value="individuel" type="radio" <TMPL_VAR IN>/> Individuel <br> <input name="ctype" value="course" type="radio" <TMPL_VAR CO>/> Course </td>
          <td class="edit-column"><a href="javascript:showhide('<TMPL_VAR ID>');">Members</a> <input value="Save" type="submit"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="<TMPL_VAR ID>" class="edit-row" style="display: none;">
          <td class="activity-data"></td>
          <td  class="activity-data" colspan="5" align="center">
            Users  <input name="users"  id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_users"  size="35" value="<TMPL_VAR US>" type="text" />
            Groups <input name="groups" id="<TMPL_VAR ID>_groups" size="35" value="<TMPL_VAR GR>" type="text" />
          </td>

          <td class="edit-column"> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </TMPL_LOOP>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try less nesting :(. Abstract it into Objects and functions. Not inlining all your anonymous functions makes things easier.

Comment: can we see the html that goes with this ?

Comment: @mcgrailm : Of course. Also added a screenshot. it is the "Create" button I click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on this line in the problem area

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

"this" is referring to the dialog itself or possible the ajax

you'll want to refer to the specific form you are trying to serialize.

i would set the value to a variable and log it to test /see what is going on there

so first figure out what

```
 $(this)
```

is by running

```
alert($(this).prop('id')) // or something similar if your using older jQuery use .attr instead of .prop
```

**EDIT**
it doesn't look like you give the form an id so i'm not 100% sure but i think you can do this

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
var aform = $(this)
.....
```

then in the problam area

```
 data: $(aform).serialize(),
```

Comment: How do I do that inside the Ajax call? I mean, I get `missing : after propery id` if I do `alert(printObject($(this).serialize()));`, where `printObject` dumps an object.

Comment: do it in the success area of the ajax call

Comment: right because "this" does not point to the form  you want to serialze so you need use a selector that points to the from

Comment: `alert($(this).prop('id'));` returns `undefined` when put in `success:`. So how do I copy (?) `$(this)`? Or are there other methods?

Comment: If I do that in the problem area, it still returns the same error `result2 is null`. If I do it in the healthy area, then it gives the same error `result is null`, but with `result` and not `result2`. So it is tempting to think, that the form_id isn't even copied when it reaches the first Ajax code.

Comment: If I do the `aform` trick, it works =) The DOM is updated like it should, but it doesn't receive the form values. So I guess I should replace all `$(this)` from the other form values with `$(aform)` for these to be transferred too?

Comment: It seams as if the `aform` doesn't contain the form values after all, but Ajax can update the DOM. So that is a huge improvement. When doing `data: $(aform).serialize(),` don't I also have to tell that it is the form elements I want in `var aform = $(this);`?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how it looks. http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1999/18807346.png Would it be correct to think, as since Ajax can update the DOM, `aform` contains the entire DOM and not just the form?

Comment: @Sandra it possible that it contains the entire dom if live (this) is referring to live if your in firefox try aler($(afrom).toSource()) and lets see what this really is

Comment: I assumed you meant `alert($(this).toSource());` ? If so, I get  `({0:#1=({}), context:#1#, length:1})` Done right below `$('form').live('submit', function(){`

Comment: well that's no help either somehow you need to ensure that your pointing to the form and I"m not sure why it's not working or how to do that

Comment: Thank you very much. It is great to know what the exact problem is rather than searching in the dark =)

Comment: @sandra your welcome, let me know if /when you figure out how to target that I would love to know how to get around that

Comment: @sandra so does alert($('form[name="create_form"]').serialize()) give you the serilzed data ?

Comment: @mcgrailm : The bug is found =) Apparently `$.ajax({` always returns an object called `result`, but in the nested Ajax I do `success: function(result2){`. Changing `result2` to `result` solved the problem combined with your excellent `aform` trick =)