# How to get form content by name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

If I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').live('submit', function(){
    var dom       = $(this);
    var all_forms = $("form");
```

**Problem**

How do I get a specific form by name and not ID?

```
<form id="create_form" name="create_form" action="" method="post">
```

**Purpose**

The reason it have to be by name is that I have many auto-generated forms, where I don't know the ID's before hand, but the names are always the same.

When I have the form, I will pass it to a nested

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",

// data: $(this).serialize(),
// data: $(form_id).serialize(),
// data: $(aform).serialize(),
```

Comment: is it possible that more than one form would be created ?

Comment: @mcgrailm : What do you mean? Right now there are ~100 forms, but only one have the `name="create_form"`. All the others don't have a name. I identify those by `<input name="anchor" value="<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="hidden">`

Comment: ok then no worries I was concerned that you might have multiple forms with the same name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('form[name="create_form"]')
```

Comment: what happens when there are forms with the same name ?

Comment: @mcgrailm This would select all of them. `name` attributes do not have to be unique. (This is why there is a `document.getElementsByName` method -- see the plural "elements".)

Comment: @mcgrailm, you can loop over them to pick the one you want or you can be more specific in your selector.

Comment: If I do `alert($('form[name="create_form"]').serialize());` it is clearly the correct form. But it still doesn't solve the actual problem I have in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044377/nested-ajax-problem-how-to-debug-solve . However I will of course accept you solution when I am allowed to do so =)