# Error running a post in a loop?

Tags: jquery, post, loops

The method

```
$.post("Dashboard/UserValuationGet", {}, function (dataSet1)
```

only runs after the post

```
$.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet))
```

is finished executing.

The code will pass my method a few times in the loops and only after execute the post method the amount of times at the end.

The problem then comes in that my local storage does not change so it will run the post method a few times on the same variable input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Show diffrent menu for Valuator and Aministrator
    getRoleMenu();


    $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataSet) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet);
        var table = obj.Table;
        var countUsers = 0;
        lis = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i++) {
            var array = table[i];
            if (array.Active == 1) {
                var name = array.Name;
                valCount = 0;


                $.post("Dashboard/UserValuationGet", {}, function (dataSet1) {

                    var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet1);
                    var table1 = obj1.Table;
                    localStorage.setItem("valCount", table1.length.toString());

                });
                valCount = localStorage.getItem("valCount");

                lis += '<li class="subitem1"><a href="#" onclick="return ShowValuationsAssigned()">' + name + '<span>' + valCount + '</span></a></li>';                    

                countUsers = countUsers + 1;
            }

        }
        $("#UserList").empty().html(lis);
        $('#userCount').html(countUsers.toString());

    });

});
```

Comment: Remove those ** from the code! :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548241/jquery-nested-ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing the `valCount` counter or the `localStorage.valCount`  in each pass of the loop, rather you are setting them to the value of the current pass. In addition you are inserting the count from storage into the html before the current ajax request has completed. AJAX is asynchronous.

Your loop needs to look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i++) {
    var array = table[i];
    if (array.Active == 1) {
        var name = array.Name;

        $.post("Dashboard/UserValuationGet", {}, function(dataSet1) {
            /* get the current count*/
            var valCount = localStorage.getItem("valCount");
            /* no need to use $.parseJSon, just set dataType of request */
            var obj1 = /*jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet1)*/ dataSet1;
            var table1 = obj1.Table;
            /* add this response to count*/
            valCount+=table1.length/*.toString()*/
            localStorage.setItem("valCount",valCount );
            /* need this inside the ajax complete callback or count won't have been updated*/
            lis += '<li class="subitem1"><a href="#" onclick="return ShowValuationsAssigned()">' + name + '<span>' + valCount + '</span></a></li>';

        },'json');/* last argument of $.post is dataType*/


        countUsers = countUsers + 1;
    }
}
```